# OOP PHP5 How create a unique class?

Tags: php, oop

I would create two main classes in PHP5:
1- Database
2- Session
These two classes will be used in a page "index.php" (and many others) in order to provide connection to the database and the use of session in future queries.
I could simply make two objects and use them as in the following example:

```
require('Session.php');
require('Database.php');

$session = new Session();
$session->startSession();

$database = new Database();
$database->query();
```

But I don't like very much this solution.
I would recall in my "index.php" just one class called Processor.php and recall both Session and Database classes too.

I would see this:

```
require('Processor.php');
$session = ...? call all methods of session
$session->
$database = ..? call all methods of database
$database->
```

How can I implement this idea?
I would make that with Singleton pattern.
Who can help me?

Comment: The purpose of a Singleton is to ensure a class has only one instance, and provide a global point of access to it. You don't need either for what you describe. If no kittens die if a second instance is instantiated, you don't need to enforce uniqueness. Simply don't instantiate a second instance. And unless you are designing around legacy code you can easily circumvent the need for global access by using Dependency Injection.